# Buttons show weirdly in my Swing calculator

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm building a calculator program using Swing. I'm writing multiple classes to build the calculator, and one of them contains a pane in which I place all of the buttons. The buttons then fire property changes that enter the screen's pane to do changes to the screen.

I'm having a problem, though. The buttons don't show up in a uniform way. Some buttons are bigger than others, and look like they are 'compressing' the other buttons.

Here's how the calculator shows up when I run the application:

[image: Calculator link]

And here is the code sample for the button pane:

```
package com.nacher.calc.ui;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelNumbers extends JPanel implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8338113083603013816L;

private GUIConstraints cons = new GUIConstraints(new int[][] {
        // la linea de enteros: {#, #}, {#, #}, {#, #}, {#,#,#,#}
        // {gridx, gridy}, {gridwidth, gridheight}, {fill, anchor}, {top, left, bottom, right}(insets)
        { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnBck 0
        { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnCE 1
        { 2, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnC 2
        { 3, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnSign  3
        { 4, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 2 }, // btnSqrt 4
        { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnSeven 5
        { 1, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnEight 6
        { 2, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnNine 7
        { 3, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnDiv 8
        { 4, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 2 }, // btnPercent 9
        { 0, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnFour 10
        { 1, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnFive 11
        { 2, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnSix 12
        { 3, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnMult 13
        { 4, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 2 }, // btnFrac 14
        { 0, 3 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnOne 15
        { 1, 3 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnTwo 16
        { 2, 3 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnThree 17
        { 3, 3 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnMinus 18
        { 4, 3 }, { 1, 2 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 2 }, // btnEquals 19
        { 0, 4 }, { 2, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnZero 20
        { 2, 4 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnComma 21
        { 3, 4 }, { 1, 1 }, { GUIConstraints.BOTH, GUIConstraints.CENT }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // btnPlus 22
},
        // La linea de decimales: {#,#}
        // {weightx, weighty}
        new double[][] { { 0.2, 0.2 }, // btnBck
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnCE
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnC
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnSign
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnSqrt
                { 0.2, 0.2 }, // btnSeven
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnEight
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnNine
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnDiv
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnPercent
                { 0.2, 0.2 }, // btnFour
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnFive
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnSix
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnMult
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnFrac
                { 0.2, 0.2 }, // btnOne
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnTwo
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnThree
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnMinus
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnEquals
                { 0.2, 0.2 }, // btnZero
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnComma
                { 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnPlus
        });
private ConstraintsGroup cg = new ConstraintsGroup(cons.getgMain(), cons.getwMain());

// Row One
JButton btnBck;
JButton btnCE;
JButton btnC;
JButton btnSign;
JButton btnSqrt;

// Row Two
JButton btnSeven;
JButton btnEight;
JButton btnNine;
JButton btnDiv;
JButton btnPercent;

// Row Three
JButton btnFour;
JButton btnFive;
JButton btnSix;
JButton btnMult;
JButton btnFrac;

// Row Four
JButton btnOne;
JButton btnTwo;
JButton btnThree;
JButton btnMinus;
JButton btnEquals;

// Row Five
JButton btnZero;
JButton btnComma;
JButton btnPlus;

Font buttonFont = new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 11);

public PanelNumbers() {
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    this.buildComponents();
    this.situateComponents();
}

private void buildComponents() {
    // Row One
    btnBck = new JButton("\u232B");
    //new ImageIcon(PanelNumbers.class.getResource(ImageConstants.BCK_ICON))
    btnBck.setIconTextGap(1);
    btnBck.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_BACK);
    btnBck.addActionListener(this);
    btnCE = new JButton("CE");
    btnCE.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnC = new JButton("C");
    btnC.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnSign = new JButton("\u00B1");
    btnSign.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnSqrt = new JButton("\u221A");
    btnSqrt.setFont(buttonFont);

    // Row Two
    btnSeven = new JButton("7");
    btnSeven.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnSeven.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_SEVEN);
    btnSeven.addActionListener(this);
    btnEight = new JButton("8");
    btnEight.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnEight.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_EIGHT);
    btnEight.addActionListener(this);
    btnNine = new JButton("9");
    btnNine.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnNine.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_NINE);
    btnNine.addActionListener(this);
    btnDiv = new JButton("/");
    btnDiv.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnPercent = new JButton("%");
    btnPercent.setFont(buttonFont);

    // Row Three
    btnFour = new JButton("4");
    btnFour.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnFour.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_FOUR);
    btnFour.addActionListener(this);
    btnFive = new JButton("5");
    btnFive.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnFive.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_FIVE);
    btnFive.addActionListener(this);
    btnSix = new JButton("6");
    btnSix.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnSix.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_SIX);
    btnSix.addActionListener(this);
    btnMult = new JButton("*");
    btnMult.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnFrac = new JButton("1/x");
    btnFrac.setFont(buttonFont);

    // Row Four
    btnOne = new JButton("1");
    btnOne.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnOne.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_ONE);
    btnOne.addActionListener(this);
    btnTwo = new JButton("2");
    btnTwo.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnTwo.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_TWO);
    btnTwo.addActionListener(this);
    btnThree = new JButton("3");
    btnThree.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnThree.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_THREE);
    btnThree.addActionListener(this);
    btnMinus = new JButton("-");
    btnMinus.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnEquals = new JButton("=");
    btnEquals.setFont(buttonFont);

    // Row Five
    btnZero = new JButton("0");
    btnZero.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnZero.setActionCommand(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_ZERO);
    btnZero.addActionListener(this);
    btnComma = new JButton(",");
    btnComma.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnPlus = new JButton("+");
    btnPlus.setFont(buttonFont);
}

private void situateComponents() {
    // Row One
    this.add(btnBck, cg.getConstraints(0));
    this.add(btnCE, cg.getConstraints(1));
    this.add(btnC, cg.getConstraints(2));
    this.add(btnSign, cg.getConstraints(3));
    this.add(btnSqrt, cg.getConstraints(4));

    // Row Two
    this.add(btnSeven, cg.getConstraints(5));
    this.add(btnEight, cg.getConstraints(6));
    this.add(btnNine, cg.getConstraints(7));
    this.add(btnDiv, cg.getConstraints(8));
    this.add(btnPercent, cg.getConstraints(9));

    // Row Three
    this.add(btnFour, cg.getConstraints(10));
    this.add(btnFive, cg.getConstraints(11));
    this.add(btnSix, cg.getConstraints(12));
    this.add(btnMult, cg.getConstraints(13));
    this.add(btnFrac, cg.getConstraints(14));

    // Row Four
    this.add(btnOne, cg.getConstraints(15));
    this.add(btnTwo, cg.getConstraints(16));
    this.add(btnThree, cg.getConstraints(17));
    this.add(btnMinus, cg.getConstraints(18));
    this.add(btnEquals, cg.getConstraints(19));

    // Row Five
    this.add(btnZero, cg.getConstraints(20));
    this.add(btnComma, cg.getConstraints(21));
    this.add(btnPlus, cg.getConstraints(22));
}

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_ONE)) {
        String v = "1";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_ONE, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_TWO)) {
        String v = "2";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_TWO, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_THREE)) {
        String v = "3";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_THREE, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_FOUR)) {
        String v = "4";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_FOUR, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_FIVE)) {
        String v = "5";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_FIVE, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_SIX)) {
        String v = "6";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_SIX, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_SEVEN)) {
        String v = "7";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_SEVEN, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_EIGHT)) {
        String v = "8";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_EIGHT, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_NINE)) {
        String v = "9";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_NINE, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_ZERO)) {
        String v = "0";
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_ZERO, null, v);
    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_BACK)) {
        this.firePropertyChange(Constants.ACTION_COMMAND_BACK, false, true);
    }
}
```

The calculator is a work in progress, but I would like to finish the buttons before doing anything else. Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Side note: for any complex layout (I'm not saying yours is but you still might profit from it) the built-in layout managers are a pain to use. There are better 3rd party layout managers such as [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure at least part of your problem are the different weights, e.g. `{ 0.2, 0.2 }, // btnBck` but `{ 0.1, 0.1 }, // btnCE` etc.

Comment: depends of value from Glyphs (returns getPreferredSize to the JButton and JButton as a final sizing value to LayoutManager) and shadowing variables GUIConstraints, ConstraintsGroup

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). To do so would mean not just to remove irrelevant code like the action listeners, but to add in imports, a `main(..)` method and whatever else is needed to put that code on-screen without any changes. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI.

Comment: `Some buttons are bigger than others, and look like they are compressing the other buttons.` - Yes a button with "CE" in the text will be slightly larger than a button with only "9" in the text. So the first two columns will be a little wider than the columns containing only a single letter in the text. The only solution for something like this is to iterate through all the buttons to find the largest size button and then manually set the preferred size of each button to this size.

Comment: Note, there is no need for the weightx/y values. Those values are only used when the frame is resized. I suspect you will be using a non-resizable frame.